# How to properly alter the output for fields of type file?

Tags: files, entities

I have a file upload field which's format is set to generic file. It prints the following markup:

```
<div class="content">
  <span class="file">
    <img class="file-icon" alt="" title="application/msword" src="project/modules/file/icons/x-office-document.png">
    <a href="urltofile.doc" type="application/msword; length=22016" title="file.doc">Lorem ipsum</a>
  </span>
  <span class="file">
    ...
  </span>
</div>
```

But I'd rather not show the img at all, alter url text, something similar like this:

```
<div class="content">

  <span class="file maybe-some-custom-classes">
    <a href="urltofile.doc">$filename</a>
    <span>$description text of this field</span>
  </span>

</div>
```

What hooks would I have to use for this? And why is this so hard to find on the docs?!

Comment: It's a field so you'd normally alter it with `field--type.tpl.php`, probably `field--file.tpl.php` for a file field

Comment: yeah but there is no tpl which renders <img /> in it markup specially for file fields, is there?

Comment: Take a look here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7

Comment: Another way, without programming, is to use Custom Formatters https://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters

Comment: @Alex not directly, but one of the contained theme functions looks to be responsible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing a bit here as I can't see what you have installed/configured...

The file formatter function is [`file_field_formatter_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!file!file.field.inc/function/file_field_formatter_view/7), and the only formatter which has an image attached to it runs through [`theme_file_link()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!file!file.module/function/theme_file_link/7). I would assume that's where the markup you're referring to comes from.

You can override that in your theme:

```
function MYTHEME_file_link($vars) {
  ...
}
```

Or, if you can get away without having to reproduce the function, just preprocess is:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_file_link(&$vars){ 
  ...
}
```

Comment: MYTHEME_file_link($vars) does the trick for me. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If it is a file field, not an image field, then it shouldn't be necessary to alter the template, but instead change the display configuration. See the attached screenshots.

Or am I misunderstanding your question?

[image]

Which then renders like this:

[image]

**Update:** Sorry, misunderstood the question, you don't want the icon in front, didn't catch that.